# Proof verification of linear independence of $\{1,x,x^2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I know that $\{1,x,x^2 \}$ is a linear independent family on $[-1,1]$, because $ax^2+bx+c$ has at most 2 roots, therefore if it equals $0$ for all $x$ of $[-1,1]$, it implies that $a=b=c=0$.

However, I am wondering if the following proof is right or not: if $ax^2+bx+c=0$ on $[-1,1]$, it is true in the particular cases $x=0$, $x=1$, $x=-1$, which implies $a=b=c=0$.

**My question:** don't we have to show this is true for all other triplets of $x$ in $[-1,1]$? Or is it sufficient to show that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ implies $a=b=c=0$ for a particular case of triplets?

Comment: You are correct.  They are linearly independent as functions $\{-1,0,1\}\to\mathbb{R}$, which is stronger than being linearly independent as functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Slade: why is being linearly independent on $\{-1,0,1\}$ stronger than on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: There is a unique quadratic through any $3$ points (with distinct $x$-values).

Comment: @Kuifje For the reason you gave.  We only need to prove that $a=b=c=0$ for any choice of $a,b,c$ such that $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot x + c\cdot x^2=0$, and it is generally harder to do that if we are only allowed to evaluate at three points, rather than infinitely many.  For example, $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ are linearly independent as functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, but _dependent_ as functions $\{-1,0,1\}\to\mathbb{R}$, since $x^3 - x$ vanishes at all three points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prove that $a=b=c=0$. Nothing more, nothing less.

You do not prove this equality **for** any given set of triplets $x$. There is no mention of $x$ in the statement "$a=b=c=0$."

What you use to prove your point is not important in the sense that as long as it proves the main point, the proof is good. Therefore, your proof can either go

$$\forall x\in[-1,1] ax^2+bx+c = 0\implies a=b=c=0$$

or
$$\forall x\in [-1,1]: ax^2+bc+c=0\implies \forall x\in\{-1,0,1\}:  ax^2+bc+c=0\implies\\\implies a=b=c=0$$

or any other way, as long as you know how to prove each implicaiton.